# Connecting to Kubernetes API Server from a service in a worker node on istio Service Mesh

Tags: c#, kubernetes, istio, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster with Istio installed. I am using Kubernetes Client for C# to perform some operations on my cluster (reading and creating secrets).
I configured appropriate cluster role and bindings for this to work :

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: secret-creator
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["create", "get", "list", "delete", "update"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: secret-creator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
```

Currently the service is in the default namespace and runs under default service account. I have PeerAuthentication and DestinationRules set up for my entire cluster like this :

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: default
spec:
  mtls: {}

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: Mdestinationrule
  namespace: default
spec:
  host: "*"
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

With these configuration in place, my service fails to communicate with the API server to using KubeClient's client.ReadNamespacedSecret(name, secretNamespace) . When I disable my destinationRule, things start working.

Due to some constraints, I cannot modify my existing destiationRules, nor can I deploy my service in a separate namespace. I need help to know if I can put some kind of filter or similar while communicating to the API server, so that the communication is not mTls?

Please advice.

Comment: What error you get? Is it Forbidden error? Can you share logs of envoy sidecar?

Comment: @Arghya, previously I was getting Forbidden, which I solved as suggested as a way in one of my previous questions by you. At that time I did not have this DestinationRule enabled on default namespace, but post enabling, I started getting this from the Kube Client Code : 

`Error in KubeClient :The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. StackTrace : System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- `

Comment: I would say your PeerAuthentication is incorrect. As far as I checked in [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/peer_authentication/#PeerAuthentication-MutualTLS-Mode) values for PeerAuthentication mtls are unset, permissive, strict and disable. Could you try to change it from  `spec:
  mtls: {}` to `spec:
  mtls:
    mode: DISABLE` and check if that works? Another thing is wildcard host in destination rules, I'm not sure if that's gonna work, it should be the name of a service from the service registry.

Comment: @Jakub mtls : {} is another way to mean "strict", so that might not be a problem. I found a way to configure the above, will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: Mdestinationrule
  namespace: default
spec:
  host: "*.kubernetes.default.svc" #Disabling it for Kube API Server communication
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
  host: "*.default.svc" 
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

Comment: This is not valid YAML, as you have the same key defined multiple times.